# Unnamed Arguments in Functions: Equivalent of R's Triple Dot

Tags: python

Coming from `R`, I was wondering if there is an equivalent in Python of `R`'s `...`?

In `R`, the triple dot can be quite useful in functions as it allows to pass any kind of arguments (named, unnamed, any type, any class, etc.). For example

```
fun <- function (...) return(list(...))
fun(a=1, b=2, weather=c("sunny", "warm"))
# returns
# $a
# [1] 1

# $b
# [1] 2

# $weather
# [1] "sunny" "warm"
```

Is there an analogous in Python?

I would like to have a similar function

```
def fun(...): return (...)
# such that
fun(a=1, b=2)
# returns
# {'a':1, 'b':2} 
# or something similar
```

Comment: checkout out `*args` and `**kwargs` & see if that answers your question.

Comment: `def fun(**kwargs):` with a body of `return kwargs` will do exactly what that example does.

Comment: Do you want the final product to be a dictionary, as you have shown?

Comment: Ah thanks guys, I was desperately trying to make it work with `*args`, `**kwargs` answers my question. @bartcubrich Not necessarily, I just wanted a way to access both names and values of *unnamed* optional arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way to receive any number of arguments:

```
def function(*arguments):
    print("received {} arguments".format(len(arguments)))
```

Then you can call it e.g. this way:

```
>>> function(5,5,6)
received 3 arguments
```

The `arguments` variable is a tuple containing all of the arguments.

On the other hand, if you want named arguments, you can do this:

```
def function(**keyword_arguments):
    print("received {} arguments".format(len(keyword_arguments)))
```

Then you can call it e.g. this way:

```
>>> function(a=4, b=7)
received 2 arguments
```

The `keyword_arguments` variable contains a dictionary of passed arguments.

See also the [Python Documentation on Keyword Arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).